# Simulating a discrete distribution on a different scale in R

Tags: r, distribution, discrete-mathematics

I'm new to R and have this question. As mentioned in the title, I have a distribution of reported dice number from students. In this task, they are given a dice with 6 faces (from 1-6) and are asked to throw it in private. The data are plotted as in the picture.

However, I wonder if it's possible that I can use this data to simulate the situation where they are given a dice with 10 faces instead (from 1-10)? How can I achieve this in R?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok second attempt if you want to use your existing six-sided die data. I use the `sn`package to fit a skewed normal distribution to your existing data and then scale it to represent a ten-sided die and make it discrete using `round`.

First I will simulate your data

```
set.seed(9999)
n=112
a = rnorm( 42, 3, 1 )
b = rnorm( 70, 5, 0.5 )
dat = round(c( a, b))
dat[!(dat %in% 1:6)] = NA
dat=dat[complete.cases(dat)]

hist(dat,breaks = seq(0.5, 6.5,1), col = rgb(0,0,1,0.25))
```

[image]

Just set `dat` as your existing data if you want.

Now to parametise the distribution using the `sn` package. (You can try to fit other distributions if you prefer)

```
require(sn)
cp.est = sn.mple(y=dat,opt.method = "nlminb")$cp 
dp.est = cp2dp(cp.est,family="SN")

##example to sample from the distribution and compare to existing
sim = rsn(n, xi=dp.est[1], omega=dp.est[2], alpha=dp.est[3])
sim = round(sim)
sim[!(sim %in% 1:6)] = NA
hist(sim,breaks = seq(0.5, 6.5,1), col = rgb(1,0,0,0.25), add=T)
```

[image]

Now scale the distribution to represent a ten-sided die.

```
sim = rsn(n, xi=dp.est[1], omega=dp.est[2], alpha=dp.est[3])/6*10
sim <- round(sim)
sim[!(sim %in% 1:10)] = NA
hist(sim,breaks = seq(0.5, 10.5,1), col = rgb(0,1,0,0.25))
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic! exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: I am glad @GAM780. Please tick to accept the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

To simulate 112 students rolling a ten-sided die and plotting the results in  histogram:

```
n=112
res = sample(1:10, size = n, replace = T)
hist(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this code will reuse the data I collected for 6-sided dice?!?